# Finding the last occurrence of a word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string:

```
<SEM>electric</SEM> cu <SEM>hello</SEM> rent <SEM>is<I>love</I>, <PARTITION />mind
```

I want to find the last "SEM" start tag before the "PARTITION" tag. not the SEM end tag but the start tag. The result should be:

```
<SEM>is <Im>love</Im>, <PARTITION />
```

I have tried this regular expression:

```
<SEM>[^<]*<PARTITION[ ]/>
```

but it only works if the final "SEM" and "PARTITION" tags do not have any other tag between them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here's your goofy Regex!!!

```
(?=[\s\S]*?\<PARTITION)(?![\s\S]+?\<SEM\>)\<SEM\>
```

What that says is "While ahead somewhere is a PARTITION tag... but while ahead is NOT another SEM tag... match a SEM tag."

Enjoy!

Here's that regex broken down:

```
(?=[\s\S]*?\<PARTITION) means "While ahead somewhere is a PARTITION tag"
(?![\s\S]+?\<SEM\>) means "While ahead somewhere is not a SEM tag"
\<SEM\> means "Match a SEM tag"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) to find PARTITION and [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) to find SEM?

```
int partitionIndex = text.IndexOf("<PARTITION");
int emIndex = text.LastIndexOf("<SEM>", partitionIndex);
```

Comment: thats really gr8 jon but wouldnt it have been much better if ud have helped me with a regex.....plz thnask anywasy

Comment: Why would it have been better?  If this method work for what you needs, why do you want to muddy the waters with regex?

Comment: Silly question... what if he needs this for a Regex validator. :)

Comment: I take the approach of only using a regex if I actually *need* a regex. Nothing in the question suggested that was a requirement - only that that was the approach taken so far.

Comment: yeah, TOTALLY don't use regex if you already have a way to do it with tokens etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use a regex to find the last occurrence of something then you might also want to use the right-to-left parsing regex option:

```
new Regex("...", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is this, i have tested in http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

```
<\s*SEM\s*>(?!.*</SEM>.*).*<\s*PARTITION\s*/>
```

As you want the last one, the only way to identify is to find only the characters that don't contain `</SEM>`.

I have included "\s*" in case there are some spaces in `<SEM> or <PARTITION/>`.

Basically, what we do is exclude the word `</SEM>` with:

```
(?!.*</SEM>.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<EM>.*<PARTITION\s*/>
```

Your regular expression was matching anything but "<" after the "EM" tag. Therefore it would stop matching when it hit the closing "EM" tag.

Comment: ya i have tried this one matches from the first SEM till the PARTITION tag...thanks anywaz

Answer (score 0):

Bit quick-and-dirty, but try this:

```
(<SEM>.*?</SEM>.*?)*(<SEM>.*?<PARTITION)
```

and take a look at what's in the C#/.net equivalent of $2

The secret lies in the lazy-matching construct (.*?) --- I assume/hope C# supports this.

Clearly, Jon Skeet's solution will perform better, but you may want to use a regex (to simplify breaking up the bits that interest you, for example).

(Disclaimer: I'm a Perl/Python/Ruby person myself...)

Comment: C# does support this but it matches from the first SEM tag till PARTITION i want the last SEM thans

Comment: Sorry, if it does that, then I suspect it ain't supporting it "properly". Could any C# regexp expert lend a hand, please?