# Getting last occurrence of a string using regular expressions

Tags: html, regex

I need to parse an HTML file and i've got something like this:

```
<TAG1>
    <TAG1>
        TEXT_TO_FIND
        KEY
        <TAG1>
        </TAG1>
        <TAG1>
        </TAG1>
    </TAG1>
</TAG1>
```

Taking into account that there are multiple nesting levels. How can I get the text TEXT_TO_FIND?

In plain english, what I need to do is to get the text between "the last  that has the text KEY after it" and "the text KEY", which only appearse once on the document.

Note1: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316855/finding-the-last-occurrence-of-a-word) but it didn't seem to work; I kept getting an empty result. This would be the expression:

```
/<TAG1>(?!.*<TAG1>)(.*)KEY/ism
```

Note2: If I remove the KEY from the expression of the previous note, I get the text from the last  to the end of file.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Regular expression are not suitable for parsing a non-regular language. Use a proper parser instead.

Comment: You are right Adam I was in a hurry, sorry. This is what i need:
Get the text between "the last <TAG1> that has the text KEY after it" and "the text KEY", which only appears once in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just don't want to use a HTML parser, this is a regexp that works if TEXT_TO_FIND does not contain "<" or ">":

```
/\s*([^<>]*?)\s*?KEY/ism
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hi everone! I need to parse an HTML file and i've got something like this:

Then you need an HTML parser. Regular Expressions aren't powerful enough to do it properly.

Once you've parsed the HTML and got the contents of each of your `TAG`s, you can use something like:

```
/(.*)KEY/is
```

to check whether the text contains `KEY` and if so, to grab the stuff that precedes it.

Answer (score 0):

Use each tool in its appropriate context: find text chunks with an HTML parser, and then match against those with regular expressions.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::Parser;

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
  api_version => 3,
  text_h => [
    sub {
      local($_) = @_;
      print $1, "\n" if /(\S.+?)\s*\bKEY\b/s;
    },
    "dtext"
  ],
);

# for demo only
*ARGV = *DATA;

undef $/;
$p->parse(<>);

__DATA__
<TAG1>
    <TAG1>
        TEXT_TO_FIND
        KEY
        <TAG1>
        </TAG1>
        <TAG1>
        </TAG1>
    </TAG1>
</TAG1>
```

Output:

```
$ ./find-text
TEXT_TO_FIND
```